# Parsing a json_encode string to use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am receiving a `json_encode` string into javascript with the following format:

```
["eq:22","dkdkd",1,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

How do I parse this string to use in javascript. I want to separate all values by comma into an array, if possible. Can someone please point me into the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: You mean `JSON.parse` ? BTW, it's JSON, not jason.

Comment: Certainly, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving it as a function variable (i.e `function myFunc(json_data))`, you'll have an indexed array where json_data[0] = "eq:22", json_data[1] = "dkdkd" and so on.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work.Try and please let me know.

```
function showJSON() {    
    var user =    
    {    
      "username":"andy",    
      "age":20,    
      "info": { "tel": "123456", "cellphone": "98765"},    
      "address":    
      [    
        {"city":"beijing","postcode":"222333"},    
        {"city":"newyork","postcode":"555666"}    
      ]    
    }    

    alert(user.username);    
    alert(user.age);    
    alert(user.info.cellphone);    
    alert(user.address[0].city);    
    alert(user.address[0].postcode);    
}
```

Comment: Note: Your example doesn't use any JSON. The syntax is similar, but this is a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) being code.